# Pattern for k distinct elements of a set of n elements

Tags: pattern-matching, combinatorics

I would like a pattern which takes as an argument a set with $n$ elements, and an integer $k$ which is less than $n$ and greater than 1, and which matches against any $k$ distinct elements of the set, in a nice elegant way.

So I'd like `ChoosePattern[set,k]` which satisfies, for example,

```
MatchQ[{a,b}, ChoosePattern[{a,b,c},2]]
MatchQ[{c,b}, ChoosePattern[{a,b,c},2]]
MatchQ[{1,2,4,3}, ChoosePattern[Range[8],4]]
MatchQ[{1,8,5,6}, ChoosePattern[Range[8],4]]
```

And doesn't match

```
MatchQ[{a,d}, ChoosePattern[{a,b,c},2]]
MatchQ[{c,b,a}, ChoosePattern[{a,b,c},2]]
MatchQ[{1,2,2,3}, ChoosePattern[Range[8],4]]
MatchQ[{1,8,5,6,7}, ChoosePattern[Range[8],4]]
```

Thank you

EDIT:
Just a small addition to kglr's very nice solution, here are my pattern and matching functions for choosing either any number, or a fixed number, or a range of possible numbers, of distinct elements from a given set;

```
ChoosePattern[set_List, 
  k_Integer] := _List?(CountDistinct[#] === k && SubsetQ[set, #] &)
ChoosePattern[
  set_List, {k1_Integer, 
   k2_Integer}] := _List?(CountDistinct[#] === Length[#] && 
     k1 <= Length[#] <= k2 && SubsetQ[set, #] &)
ChoosePattern[
  set_List] := _List?(CountDistinct[#] === Length[#] && 
     SubsetQ[set, #] &)
ChooseQ[set_List, subset_List, k_Integer] := 
 MatchQ[subset, ChoosePattern[set, k]]
ChooseQ[set_List, subset_List, {k1_Integer, k2_Integer}] := 
 MatchQ[subset, ChoosePattern[set, {k1, k2}]]
ChooseQ[set_List, subset_List] := MatchQ[subset, ChoosePattern[set]]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Also

```
ClearAll[cKp]
cKp[e_,n_]:= _List?(CountDistinct[#] == n && SubsetQ[e, #]&)
```

Comment: Very elegant thank you

Comment: @Joe, thank you for the accept.

Answer (score 7):

This seems to pass all those tests:

```
ChooseKPattern[elems_List, n_Integer] := Block[{list}
, Condition @@ Hold[
    list_List
  , Length[DeleteDuplicates @ list] == n && ContainsAll[elems, list]
  ]
]
```

Comment: this works too...`Hold[list_List, Length@Intersection[elems, list] == n]` (I don't have `ContainsAll` ..)

Comment: Thank you this is nice and it works